# How do i calculate sum of rows from text file?

Tags: python

Im new to programming and i needed help with one of my assignments. (not asking for a solution). Im confused how to approach this problem. If you can provide pseudocode to get me in the right direction it be helpful.

So far,

1. Take an input for a file
2. Read Files testFile = inputFile.read()
3. This is where i'm confused. I know there needs to be a for loop to go through the text file. calculate sum for line in testFile: //Logic

Refer to [Text File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQCRC.png) for text file and corresponding expected output.

So for example: without using lens function

x = input("enter a file to read: ")
y = input("enter a file to write: ")

filereading = x.readline()

what characters do i need to strip in order to get the two values to add. Also i need the output to have $ # with a space in between.

for line in filereading:
\logic

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow. Please post the code you have tried out along with errors if any.

Comment: Is the input file a csv file?

Comment: Good to see that StackOverflow is proactively protecting new users. :)

Comment: The file is from .txt

Comment: I added some my code its at the for loop that has me confused new to python. I do not want to use methods such as len which i have not covered yet. i have learned the file reading with split,strip methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pseudocode**

```
open file as test_file

read test_file into something
split something to make list out of something 

loop through something 
    remove $ from all items in something

open other_file to write to

create loop to sum 2 consecutive items in something
    create variable to hold total of two items
    write output statement to other_file
```

Tried to write out an idea how I handled it in words to help guide you, below is the answer, again not for you to skip to but to use as a guide if you get stuck .

...

...

...

...

**SPOILER: Solution**

```
test_file = open('money.txt', 'r')

content = test_file.read()
content = content.split()

for i in range(len(content)):
    content[i] = content[i].strip('$')

other_file = open('print.txt', 'w')

for i in range(0, len(content), 2):
    total = float(content[i]) + float(content[i+1])
    other_file.write(f"${content[i]} + ${content[i+1]} = ${total}\n")

test_file.close()
other_file.close()
```

**Additional**

```
with open(other_file, 'w') as f_obj:
    total = float(content[0]) + float(content[1])
    f_obj.write("$ " + content[0] + " $ " + content[1] + " $ " + 
        str(total) + "\n")
    total = float(content[2]) + float(content[3])
    f_obj.write("$ " + content[2] + " $ " + content[3] + " $ " + 
        str(total) + "\n")
    total = float(content[4]) + float(content[5])
    f_obj.write("$ " + content[4] + " $ " + content[5] + " $ " + 
        str(total) + "\n")
```

Here is an example on how to manually enter each statement, also note if you use `with open` like in this example, the file should `close` after the `with open` code is completed

Comment: So for example: without using lens function

x = input("enter a file to read: ") y = input("enter a file to write: ")

filereading = x.readline()

what characters do i need to strip in order to get the two values to add. Also i need the output to have $ # with a space in between.

Comment: Sorry no longer home, on phone but if you used `for i in content` I think you would run into problems getting the second item in the same loop to sum, maybe someone else has a better response. But you could manually do everything with no loop `total = sum(content[0], content[1]) ` and so forth prob have to check format of variables , again sorry on phone trying my best

Comment: You can .strip(‘$’) to get the values , and then just insert the ‘$’ in your output statement like I did . Or you could make a loop and add ‘$’ back too each item after your calculations and then pull them again from your new list to print

Comment: Okay and I’ll be home in the am I could write out what that should look like as well